# How to get filterByText() to filter out blank cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using an ArrayLib function to filter the blank cells out of my results but i can't get it to filter when i use numColumn.

I am calling a Ui promt including data from a set of rows/columns but i want it to ignore any blank cells. Currently i get a lot of commas when there is a blank.

I have tried to use a filter(string) but this won't filter the results in my getRange(row, col, numRows, numColumns) only when i have used getRange(row, col, numRows). (See code below)

I then found an ArrayLib filter that i was told could work but still has the same results, or it filters out everything.

```
var LiDCO = ss.getRange(3, 15, 9).getValues();    
var filtered_input = LiDCO.filter(String);
```

doesn't work when using multiple columns.

```
var filters = ss.getRange(3, 13, 9, 2).getValues();    
var unique_filters = ArrayLib.unique(filters);
var filtered_input1 = ArrayLib.filterByText(filters, -1, "");
```

Either filters out every cell or doesn't filter at all.

Comment: Use your time to learn how [``Array#filter``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) works instead of searching for libraries.

Comment: Wow i've just looked through those and i'm even more confused (i am a novice at all of this). I really can't get this filter to work correctly.

Comment: Not to say that @TheMaster is wrong, but when you shift to multiple columns, you also shift to ARRAYLIB. In that case, filter is part of the [ArrayLib Documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library#TOC-Reference-documentation). Because there is an example in the documentation, you should be able to adapt it to your situation. Having said that, there's an expectation that you should do your own research **BEFORE** you submit a question; I don't think it is asking too much to work through the ARRAYLIB stuff.

Comment: @Tedinoz thanks for your comment. I have read the ArrayLib documentation several times and tried what i thought would work and various other combinations of code, but with no joy. That is why I came here for assistance. If anyone is able to help me that would be great.

Comment: Yes I tried filterByText(Object[][] data, int columnIndex, String[] values)
(The one in my question)
But I must be doing it wrong at I could only get it to filter out everything or nothing. I just want the empty cells skipped.

Comment: Shouldn't `filterByText` reference `unique_filters` rather than `filters`? (untested)

Comment: Possibly, but I don't want only unique cells, I want all cells with text. I tried the unique_filter as that's what was shown on the ArrayLib doc. I tried without the previous unique filter and still came up short.

Comment: I don't see that ArrayLib can cope with this (not that I'm an expert by any means). BUT, is there is reason why you didn't attack this by the usual looping by row? I think the code would be written by now and you'd be on your way ;)

Comment: BTW, did you consider, and rule out using `QUERY` and/or `FILTER`?

Comment: I am using getRange to populate a ui.prompt so I don't think a query is what I need. Clearly I'm not great at this so is there somewhere I can learn how to loop by row?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a suggestion from @Tedinoz, using a separate code i have ensured that all cells within the range are unique, then the `filterByText(unique_filters)` reference works to clear out any empty cells and includes all `numColumns`.

Comment: Congrats. Would you post your final "successful" code so that, in the future, others don't have to dig through the comments to interpret your answer? I'm also intrigued about how this filtered out rows with blank cells; is there anything you can add to explain that?